# Physically understanding Dilation Symmetry of Eigenvalue-Eigenvector Identity

Tags: symmetry, neutrinos, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

In the [recent paper by Tao](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.03795) concerning the famous eigenvalue-eigenvector identity, I need some insight regarding the "Dilation Symmetry" from a physical perspective.

It is mentioned that if we assign units to the entries of $A$, then the eigenvalues of $A$, $M_j$ acquire the same units, while $v_{i,j}$ remains dimensionless, and the identity (2) is dimensionally consistent.

The actual identity (2) given in the paper is :
([Eigenvector-eigenvalue identity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.03795)).
$$
\left|v_{i, j}\right|^{2} \prod_{k=1 ; k \neq i}^{n}\left(\lambda_{i}(A)-\lambda_{k}(A)\right)=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\lambda_{i}(A)-\lambda_{k}\left(M_{j}\right)\right) \tag{2}
$$
where $A$ is an $n \times n$ Hermitian matrix, and its $n$ real eigenvalues are $\lambda_{1}(A), \ldots, \lambda_{n}(A)$, $M_{j}$ denote the $n-1 \times n-1$ minor formed from $A$ by deleting the $j^{\text {th }}$ row and column from $A$ and $v_{i, j}$ denote the $j^{\text {th }}$ component of $v_{i}$.

And Dilation Symmetry is defined as "If one multiplies the matrix $A$ by a real scalar $c$, then the eigenvalues of $A$ and $M_j$ also get multiplied by c, while the coefficients $v_{i,j}$ remain unchanged, which does not affect the equation (2)

It would be very helpful of someone can actually provide an physical example of this "Dilation Symmetry". Because personally I couldn't understand what kind of
If you could provide me with some physical example of this "Dilation Symmetry", that would be extremely useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moment of inertia tensor could be an example.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia#List_of_3D_inertia_tensors

If one doubles the mass of a solid ellipsoid, 
then the eigenvalues double, but the principal directions remain the same.